# How to find maximum weight independent set for a tree using dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic, tree

I have this problem that I am trying to solve:

> You are given a tree T with n nodes. Each node has a non-negative weight assigned to it. Our goal is to
> find a set S of nodes such that (i)no two nodes in S are adjacent, and (ii)the total weight of all vertices
> in S is maximal. Such a set is called maximum weight independent set.
> Assignment
> Implement a Dynamic Programming algorithm that finds a maximum weight independent set for a given
> tree in O(n)time. If there are multiple such sets, return a set with maximum number of nodes.
> Implementation

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find the answer for a tree (not a path!). By the way, the tree is implemented using an edges double array, and an array of weights. Can someone help me solve it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also have access to bfs and dfs, and that the tree is undirected and is represented by adjacency list

Comment: One of the first search results I got for that phrase talks about trees: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2011/Lectures/09_lec.pdf

Comment: Since you're looking for the algorithm this question could be language agnostic and leave off the language tag, but I really think it's too broad for SO.

Comment: it's for java @DavidConrad

Comment: @DavidConrad I saw this search result but I don't know how to implement it in my code

Comment: *"but I don't know how to implement it in my code"*: that is quite vague. Show your attempt and where in the coding you get into an issue (specific).